# Check if a value of a Vector are in Set<String>

Tags: java, vector, set

I'm trying to find if a vector contains any value from a set and if it there throw an exception, here is what I've tried, don't know if it is right, which doesn't give the result :

```
//This method returns of List type itself.
List<String> listUniqueIds = DataAccessSessionBeanBase.queryToVector(strQuery);

//gives a set of strings
HashSet<String> setUniqueIds = getUniqueIds(objRtElement);
for(String strUniqueId : setUniqueIds)
{
    System.out.println("strUniqueId : "+strUniqueId);
    if(vecUniqueIds.contains(strUniqueId))
    {
        throw new Exception("Incorrect values");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is doing the inverse of what your description says. Please, stop using Vector. It's obsolete since Java 2. And don't use raw types. It should be a Vector<String>, not a Vector.

Comment: What type of Objects are in the `Vector`? If not `String`, there will never be a match.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm forced to use vector as it is legacy code, but anyway, I've updated it and how could I find out in a better way?

Comment: I already said that: stop using raw types: it should be a List<String>, not a List. And fix the code, since it does the inverse of what your description says. If it's not a List<String>, then read and answer Eran's comment.

Comment: @JBNizet Alright, I changed it, it gives the same result. And pardon me, I don't get if my description says inverse. By iterating through the set, I'm verifying if each of the element is contained in the vector. That's how I meant it.

Comment: So, what does the list contain precisely, what does the set contain precisely, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Both of them contain a values of String type. If there is a common value among them, i.e., if the vector contains a value that is there in the set, then throw an exception, which is not happening.

Comment: Which simply indicates that there is no value in the set that is also contained in the list. If you answered my questions, you would figure that out by yourself, or we could at least help you figure it out. So, what does the list contain precisely, what does the set contain precisely, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204412/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with what you're doing but if you want to use Java 8 streams you could try:

```
if(setUniqueIds.stream().filter(listUniqueIds::contains).findAny().isPresent()) {
    throw new Exception("Incorrect values");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer of @Cwrwhaf, you can even entirely omit the if, and use [`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)

```
setUniqueIds.stream()
    .filter(listUniqueIds::contains)
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Incorrect values"));
```

Comment: very nice, didn't think of that!